# How to get timebased data from MSSQL 2008 aggregated at time interval

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have an equipment that reports its number of produced pieces at random time intervals. At each record, the internal counter is reset, so if I want to get the total pieces, I would net to sum over an interval.

```
ts                      pieces
--------------------------------
2013-01-23 11:58        2013   
2013-01-23 12:12        3025
2013-01-23 12:12        3025
2013-01-23 12:13        112
2013-01-23 12:17        1122
2013-01-23 12:34        3112
2013-01-23 12:36        3025
```

What if I want to query this data and I want the produced pieces from 12:00 to 12:30. I cannot simply do the following:

```
SELECT SUM(pieces) 
FROM table 
WHERE ts BETWEEN '2013-01-23 12:00' and '2013-01-23 12:30'
```

With this query, I would have too many pieces in the beginning (as of the 3025 pieces reported at 12:12 some were produced in the 2 minutes before 12:00) and I would have too little pieces at the end (pieces produced between 12:17 and 12:30 were only reported at 12:34).

Is there a built in feature in SQL server to do such calculations on timebased series, or would it require me to manually interpolate based on dateDiff between first/last values in the interval and last/first outside?

Comment: So we have to assume that the production rate is fixed and so `12/14 * 3025` pieces were produced between 12:00 and 12:12 (despite the fact that we have evidence elsewhere that pieces aren't produced at a fixed rate)?

Comment: Yes. You can indeed make that assumption. Actually, separate from this data, I also have intervals in which the machine is stopped en in which it is running. Ideally, I should be able to spread the produced pieces in some way over the intervals the machine is actually producing, but to keep things 'simple' I thought I'd start by trying to achieve the above :-)

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the interpolation manually. I've built some code that does it, based on various other assumptions (i.e. whether `ts` represents "all items produced up until and including this minute" or "all items produced before this minute"):

```
declare @t table (ts datetime2 not null,pieces int not null)
insert into @t(ts,pieces) values
('2013-01-23T11:58:00',2013),  
('2013-01-23T12:12:00',3025),
--('2013-01-23T12:12:00',3025), --Error, two identical counts at same time?
('2013-01-23T12:13:00',112 ),
('2013-01-23T12:17:00',1122),
('2013-01-23T12:34:00',3112),
('2013-01-23T12:36:00',3025)

declare @Start datetime2
declare @End datetime2
select @Start = '2013-01-23T12:00:00', @End = '2013-01-23T12:30:00'

;With Numbers as (
    select distinct number
    from master..spt_values
), RowsNumbered as (
    select
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ts) as rn,
        *
    from @t
), Paired as (
    select
        rn2.ts as prevTime,
        rn1.ts as thisTime,
        rn1.pieces as pieces
    from
        RowsNumbered rn1
            inner join
        RowsNumbered rn2
            on
                rn1.rn = rn2.rn + 1
), Minutes as (
    select
        DATEADD(minute,-number,thisTime) as Time,
        (pieces * 1.0) / DATEDIFF(minute,prevTime,thisTime) as Pieces
    from
        Paired p
            inner join
        Numbers n
            on
                number < 60 and --Reasonable?
                DATEADD(minute,-number,thisTime) > prevTime and
                number >= 0
)
select SUM(pieces)
from Minutes
where Time >= @Start and Time < @End
```

I'm also treating the start and end times as a semi-open interval with an inclusive start and exclusive end. This is normally the more sensible way to work with continuous data such as datetime.

Hopefully, you can see how I'm building up each CTE to get from the individual timestamps and piece counts to, for each minute, having a concept of how many pieces were produced in that minute. Once we've got to that point, we can just `SUM` over the minutes we want to include.